# How to efficiently calculate $a^k \bmod m$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

How can I efficiently calculate $a^k \bmod m$ where $a,k,m$ are very large numbers and $k$ might be up to $10^9$ or more, $a$ might be up to $10^6$.

Here $a$ is a prime but $k$ and $m$ might not be primes.

Is my only option to calculate $a^1 \bmod m$, $a^2 \bmod m$, $a^4 \bmod m$ etc or is there any way to reduce $k$ to a smaller number?

Comment: Look in google: Binary exponentiation.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring

Comment: Hm, being prime might be useful for any of the numbers - except for $a$.

Comment: You say that $m$ might not be a prime, in which case it would be helpful to know if $m$ can be factored into primes.

Comment: yes m can be factored into primes

Comment: Bounds like $10^9$ and $10^6$ suggest that this is from a programming competition - which one? Usually, such bounds hint to the expected $O()$ your algorithm should have.

Comment: The Chinese Remainder Theorem can be used if $m$ is composite (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem). Also $k$ can be reduced by taking advantage of $a^{\phi(m)}=1\ (mod\ m)$ if $\gcd(a,m)=1$ and $k>\phi(m)$.